# Cannot convert type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'

Tags: c#

Is there any way to convert `mshtml.IHTMLDocument2` to `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`. I have the following code:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = CrossFrameIE.GetDocumentFromWindow(frmdoc);
HtmlDocument doc1 = (HtmlDocument)doc2 ;
```

it gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' error.

thanks

Comment: simple and easiest fix, do a simple and quick google on the exact error message `Cannot convert type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' `

Comment: i did but all results are about HtmlDocument to IHTMLDocument2 i found nothing usefull

Comment: What do you want to do with a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` that you can't do with an `mshtml.IHTMLDocument2`?

Comment: i want to reach a textbox and change it value but it is so slow with IHTMLdocument

i have to use

     IHTMLElementCollection itemler = doc3.body.all;
     foreach (IHTMLElement item in itemler)
    {
       string id = item.id;
    }

Comment: That conversion is just not possible.  IHTMLDocument2 is the COM interop type, HtmlDocument is the Winforms wrapper type.  It has a private constructor, you can only ever get a valid HtmlDocument object when you use the WebBrowser.Document property.  It just isn't necessary, the COM interop type can do everything that the wrapper can do.  And more.  Not showing what you *want* to do is a classic mistake, it doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
    public static HtmlDocument ConvertCom2Wrapper(IHTMLDocument2 idoc)
    {
        Type thd = typeof(HtmlDocument);
        ConstructorInfo[] ci = thd.GetConstructors(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        HtmlDocument hdoc = (HtmlDocument)ci[0].Invoke(new object[] { null, idoc });
        return hdoc;
    }
```